# what is meant by largest_cc in graph

Tags: python, networkx, connected-components

i am trying to create a graph where i encountered a term called largest connected component

so i want to understand what is actually meant by it.

Suppose i have a graph G and if i apply below code snipet will given the nodes

```
largest_cc = max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)
```

Suppose there are 10 nodes in graph g (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10)

and there is edge between ((a1,a2),(a3,a6),(a1,a4),(a1,a8),(a1,a9),(a5,a10),(a7,a8),(a8,a10))

so largest connected component will given me the nodes a1,a2,a4,a8 as a1 has maximum number of edges present??

is my understanding right? or there is something else

Answer (score 0):

A connected component in an undirected graph is a collection of nodes such that you can get from any node of the component to any other by following edges.  The largest component is the component with the most nodes.

Imagine each edge is a string.  You grab one node and pull it out of a pile, and keep pulling out nodes until there's no more pieces of string connecting the nodes you've pulled out into the remaining pile of nodes.  What you've pulled out is the connected component of the initial node you grabbed.

So no in your example `a3` and `a6` would make up a connected component (they don't have any other edges), but the remaining nodes also make up a connected component (since you can get from any one of them to any other).  This component of the other nodes is the largest.

Comment: thanks joel. i have one more questioned which if i want to find number of nodes in the largest connected component in the graph then len of largest_cc will be the value for that?

Comment: The size of a graph is the length of the enumeration of its nodes, yes.

Answer (score 0):

A connected component in a graph is a set of nodes that are linked to each other by paths of any length, not just the nodes directly connected to the node with the most edges. Let's draw the graph and see what we're working with.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

edges = [('a1', 'a2'), ('a3', 'a6'), ('a1', 'a4'), ('a1', 'a8'),
         ('a1', 'a9'), ('a5', 'a10'), ('a7', 'a8'), ('a8', 'a10')]
G.add_edges_from(edges)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax=ax, node_size=500, node_color="cyan")
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, ax=ax, font_weight='bold', font_size=12)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=ax, edgelist=edges, edge_color="b")

plt.show()

largest_cc = max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)
print(largest_cc)
```

The first output is to display the graph, which will be something like this:

[image: a graph showing two connected components]

The graph is divided into two connected components. One small one with just the nodes `(a3, a6)` and one large one with all of the remaining nodes. The large sub-graph on the bottom right is what will be returned as the largest connected component.

```
{'a5', 'a10', 'a1', 'a7', 'a2', 'a9', 'a4', 'a8'}
```